# How can i integrate a section in Related Lists with the standard Lead Page

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, standardlayout

Could you please help me to know, how can i integrate a section with the standard Lead Page. I have tried to embed a visual force section into a standard page layout, I can add that section in "lead detail", but looking for a way to add the same section outside lead detail or  in "Related Lists".[image: Please See Image] 
Is it possible?
I have been searching for this from couple of weeks,Your time and help is cordially appreciated....!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot insert Visualforce customizations in the Related List portion of the page layout. Visualforce pages may only be embedded in the Details section.

Your only option would be to fully reimplement the View action for this object in Visualforce, which would take a great deal more code.